# Monero daemon log rotation

Tags: monerod, error-log, logs

I'm looking for a way to:

1) Use the log rotation feature of `monerod`.
2) **And** be able to do `tail -f monerod.log | dosomething.sh`

Currently the log-rotation is done by (something like) close the current log-file, rename it to `monerod.log-<current-date-time>` and opening a new file.

At this point, above `tail` command is no longer following the current log-file.

I have been searching the source files, for the log rotation functions, with no luck.

Is there a way to accomplish this, without changes in source, or where should I look to make those changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: "tail -F bitmonero.log" ? This follows the name and works with rename and creation of a new file. I've not tried it with monerod though.

Comment: @user36303 That actually seems to work.  It's like a `follow filename` instead of `follow file handle` right?  I would prefer a more clean way, like `morerod`did the file handeling, but I will test this out.